# MVC IClientValidatable Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entitySet

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, null

```
public class FlaggedPublishedSongViewModel : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PublishedSongId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalDetails { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("AdditionalDetails", AdditionalDetails);
        rule.ValidationType = "isempty";
        yield return rule;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestDeletion(FlaggedPublishedSongViewModel song)
{
    db.FlaggedPublishedSongs.Add(song);

    db.SaveChanges();

    TempData["UserMessage"] = "Thank you for the report";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

@model SoundVast.Areas.Music.Models.FlaggedPublishedSongViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

      @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.PublishedSongId)

      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Reason, "Quality", new { @class = "radio-button-list" })     
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Reason, "Duplicate", new { @class = "radio-button-list" }) 
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Reason, "Copyright", new { @class = "radio-button-list" }) 
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Reason, "Inappropriate", new { @class = "radio-button-list" }) 
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Reason, "Other", new { @class = "radio-button-list" }) 

      @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.AdditionalDetails, new { @class = "additional-details", @placeholder = "Please be specific about any additional details" })

      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-default">Flag Song</button>
}
```

Jquery file:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("isempty", "AdditionalDetails");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("isempty",
    function (val, element, other) {
        var modelPrefix = element.name.substr(
                            0, element.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        var otherVal = $("[name=" + modelPrefix + other + "]").val();
        if (val && otherVal) {
            if (val.toUpperCase() == "OTHER" && other.length <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

I'm trying to add client validation for `"Other"` radio checkbox and the text area.
Inherting from ValidationAttribute seems to cause the error: "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entitySet", when I try to do any action on my database, e.g. db.PublishedSongs.ToList();

If I don't inherit from this base class, my application runs but the validator.addMethod never gets run through. I have also included Jquery validation ajax and validation unob.
The jquery `addSingleVal` and `addMethod` both get declared fine with no errors, so I presume it's my viewmodel that's wrong.

Comment: You seem to be completely misunderstanding what an `Attribute` is. You apply attributes to properties of you model. A model does not inherit `ValidationAttribute` or implement `IClientValidatable`.

Comment: I am following this tutorial. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/23/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-ii-client-code.aspx

Which inherits from `ValidationAttribute`.

Edit: Ah yes, it's a custom attribute class. Thanks.

Comment: And you have misunderstood it. You create a another class (in that case `DateGreaterThanAttribute`) and you then apply that to a property in your model - for example if you had a model with `DataTime` properties for `StatDate` and `EndDate` you then use it as `[DateGreaterThan("StartDate")] public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }`. I suggest you study [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1) for a more complete example.